# How to update Android app automatically, without "yes/no" prompts?

Tags: android, auto-update

I have a problem with updating an Android app. My requirements to the application  are:

- It must work constantly (24/7);
- Updating should also be automatic, with no user input.

I uploaded the application to the developer console to conduct beta-testing. Then, I installed it on the tablet (I used URL).
Then, I uploaded  the update, but the application does not start the updating process automatically. 
There are no added additional permissions. The "automatic updates" are turned on in Play Market settings.
4 days have passed. If I go to the app's page in the market, I see that an update is available, but it does not start the download process.

The question is: what may be the problem? Why does the app not update?

Is it possible that the app gets reinstalled instead of an update (thus requiring some user input to proceed)?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

in Google play store app, open side menu, go to settings, enable auto update apps. It should do the trick

Comment: `... The "automatic updates" are turned on in Play Market settings.`

Comment: As Rotwang said (and as I said), the updates box is ticked.

Answer (score 0):

The Google Play auto update solution does not seem to work, when the app is always running. The way to achieve it through enterprise management tools.